# Order of (nolock) and table aliases on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

So I've got a SQL statement that pared down looks something like this:

```
SELECT column
FROM table t (nolock)
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 (nolock) t2 on t.id = t2.id
```

This statement works on my SQL 2005 and SQL 2008 environments. It does not on a remote SQL 2005 environment. I've switched the last line to:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 (nolock) on t.id = t2.id
```

This works in the remote environment.

Putting aside issues of whether (nolock) is appropriate and that the syntax should remain internally consistent, any ideas why this happens? I attempted to search for hotfixes/KBs that dealt with this and came up with nothing. Is there a setting on SQL server that could cause this behavior?

Comment: What compatibility level is the database set to?

Comment: what does "works" and "It does not on.." mean, you get an error message and/or locking?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check your database compatibility level.

It should be `90` for this syntax to work.

Just checked:

```
sp_dbcmptlevel 'test', 80

DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM master t (nolock)
LEFT OUTER JOIN master (nolock) t2 on t.id = t2.id

Сообщение 102, уровень 15, состояние 1, строка 3
Incorrect syntax near 't2'.
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure but maybe it is caused by [compatibility level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191137.aspx)?

Since SQL 2005 by default correct syntax of hint is `WITH (NOLOCK)` and maybe this is the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1194913/2200690, 
if the name of your database is AdventureWorks, the following SQL can be used to find out the compatibility level :

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
SELECT compatibility_level  
FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'AdventureWorks2012';  
GO
```